# justifying links text

Tags: html, css, text

I'm working on CSS design of a website... whenever links are posted, they are formatted like

http://img4.ru/images/2012/12/29/lO5z.png

As you see, the right side is not aligned.

How can I turn it into something like

http://img4.ru/images/2012/12/29/btxDU.png

I've tried all what I knew...

```
text-align:jutify, letter-spacing, etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enclose links in `<pre></pre>` tag, which will give the desired look.

Comment: oh! the problem is because of inheritance... your solution is OK. thank you.

Comment: The `pre` element does more than just make the font-family monospaced.

Comment: This is not a good answer. `pre` is used for preformatted text, so linebreaks, multiple spaces etc are preserved. The user style sheet happens to have monospace set as the font family, but this isn't what the tag is for and may later have unexpected consequences.

Answer (score 5):

Make the font monospaced, Menlo for Macs, Consolas for Win 7+, or even Courier New are a fairly standard font for this.

In your CSS use:

```
.whatever-class {
    font-family: Menlo, Consolas, Courier New, monospace;
}
```

will do the job.

Comment: It didn't make any changes.

Comment: @Pazis you're going to have to be a little more specific as to how it "didn't make any changes".  A the characters in a monospaced font have a fixed width, meaning all phrases with the same number of characters in them will take up the same amount of horizontal space.

Comment: oh! the problem is because of inheritance... your solution is OK. thank you

Comment: On the other hand, monospace font will make them right-justified only if they have exactly the same number of characters. (I can’t guess why they *should* be right-justified.)